# Adding more drop down or html elements to Datatable in Jquery

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

Is it possible to add more drop down or other html elements to the Datatable after the default

**Display "5" record**

I want to add more drop down to my DataTable between the Default one and the Search Bar which is provided by default.

I have gone through sDom but I am not able to understand the syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert an element `<div>` between the length menu and the filter box this way :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   dom : 'l<"#add">frtip'
})
```

`'lfrtip'` is the default `dom` string, so you basically just add an `<div id="#add">` to the existing layout. It is adviceable to style `#add`, especially setting the `display` type to `inline-block` so it not break the elements down under :

```css
#add {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

Now you can add `<select>`'s (or whatever) to the `#add` element the plain jQuery way :

```js
//insert a label
$('<label/>').text('my dropdown').appendTo('#add')

//insert the select and some options
$select = $('<select/>').appendTo('#add')
$('<option/>').val('1').text('option #1').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('2').text('option #2').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('3').text('option #3').appendTo($select);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ahqbf35w/**

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your response and answer.

Comment: how to add another element to the div?

Comment: @SapneshNaik,  you can do it the exact same way; have added an additional `<input>` with an `ID` here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ahqbf35w/22/**