# Jquery data-table : Filter/Search based on select box outside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I'm using the dataTables jQuery plugin on a table, but I want to add a Filter Column drop-down box before the search box. I see documentation for adding drop-down boxes to individual columns but I want to add just one drop-down box which has all the column names. I am new to this and would greatly appreciate any help. I have added my code below.

HTML:

```
<select id='mySelector'>
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value='Name'>Name</option>
   <option value='Highlights'>Highlights</option>
   <option value='Area'>Area</option>
</select>
<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable" cellspacing="0">
    @{int rowNo = 0;}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Item
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Highlights)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Area)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i + 1 }))
        {
            rowNo++;
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @rowNo.ToString("000")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Highlights)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Area)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Data.id}) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Data.id}) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Data.id})
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128094/adding-more-drop-down-or-html-elements-to-datatable-in-jquery

Comment: My aim is to have a drop-down of column names(not values) and when I type the search value, I want the table to show records that have that value in the selected column alone(as opposed to all the columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I add the dropdown option to select which column to search.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom : 'l<"#add">frtip'
})  

$('<label/>').text('Search Column:').appendTo('#add')
$select = $('<select/>').appendTo('#add')

$('<option/>').val('All').text('All').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('0').text('Seq').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('1').text('Name').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('2').text('Position').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('3').text('Office').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('4').text('Start Date').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('5').text('Salary').appendTo($select);

$('input[type="search"]').on( 'keyup change', function () {
    var searchValue = $(this).val();
    var columnSearch = $select.val();

    if(columnSearch == 'All'){
        table.search(searchValue).draw();
    } else {
        table.columns(columnSearch).search(searchValue).draw();
    }
});
```

**Here is the [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/saf21/anwdL8oh/5/) for the code above.**

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Quick follow-up. Would you have any suggestions for doing this search on click of a button instead of keyup change ?

Comment: Not understand regarding the button. Do you mean replace the dropdown with button for every column. So you can click few button to search for few column. Is it right?